# Making html content unbreakable (in one line)

Tags: css, html

I have a line made of `input`s and `span`s which should represent a phone number. Inserting it into a table with some columns with content causes the line to break:

[image: broken line]

The last input is pushed into the next line. One way to fix this could be setting a fixed `td` `width` or `min-width`. However, for the sake of any future projects I would like to know is there a way to make the html content unbreakable without touching the `td` width. Thanks for any info.

Comment: why would you put every digit in a seperate input ?

Comment: Because I was requested to do so :).

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Add this CSS to the td

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

This prevents the automatic line-breaking of HTML. For more info see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/white-space)

Comment: Thank you all for your fast responses, sadly I can accept only one of them. I accepted @Sirko's one because of the link to MDN which makes this answer a little more complete.

Answer (score 17):

add

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

to your css

Answer (score 15):

Using [`white-space: nowrap`](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/whitespace.html) should get the job done.

Answer (score 2):

In bootstrap it's a class `text-nowrap`.